# grails release plugin 3.0.0 unresolved error

Tags: grails, plugins, maven-release-plugin

I was trying to run maven-install to put my plugin in the local maven cache, but it gave me unresolved dependencies error:  #release;3.0.0: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://plugins.grails.org/grails-release/tags/RELEASE_3_0_0/release-3.0.0.pom': bad organisation: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'; 
Is the problem in my environment? I would like to eventually publish my plugin to the company remote repository. I have this in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
    }
    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies 
    build ":release:3.0.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install a plugin, put it the `plugins` section, not in the `dependencies` section, since `dependencies` is for jars.

But `release` plugin version 3.0.0 requires Grails version 2.3 or higher, and that's unreleased. Use version 2.2.1 instead, and be sure to not export it or its dependent rest-client-builder plugin:

```
plugins {
   build ':release:2.2.1', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.3', {
      export = false
   }
}
```